# Как проверить, сохранены ли все данные из поле на странице?

Tags: javascript, html

Добрый день. Имеется таблица с товарами. У каждого товара есть возможность редактировать несколько полей. Сохраняются данные через AJAX (для каждого товара своя кнопка Сохранить).

Также есть внизу навигация. Как сделать так, чтобы при попытке покинуть страницу (закрыть) или перейти по навигации, осуществлялась проверка, сохранены ли изменения в полях товара или нет. Если нет, то выдавать сообщение.

---

Я пока вижу вариант следующий. При изменении данные полей товара записывать в скрытый input сообщение (например, 1) о том, что поля подверглись изменению. А при сохранении очищать значение этого input. Тем самым при навигации я могу делать проверку за наполнение таких input-ов.

Но может есть более правильное решение?

Comment: А почему вы не можете эти "1" заносить в переменную JS ?

Comment: Хороший вариант. Мне нравится. Похоже с input-ом, но более универсален. Спасибо.

Answer (score 3):

Лично я предпочитаю помечать измененные инпуты специальным классом, например dirty.

```
$("#mytable input").change(function() {
    $(this).addClass("dirty");
});
```

И проверить легко:

```
if($("#mytable .dirty").length) { ..... }
```

и визуально можно подсветить с помощью css:

```
#mytable .dirty {
    background: #ffffaa;
}
```

UPD: ну и при сохранении не забываем чистить

```
$(".....").removeClass("dirty");
```